# Validation best approach while looping fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a save button handler inside which i check the employee name , skills and level for the employee which can be in multiple. I need the best possible way to do it as i am certain the way i do it looks really messy. Thanks

JS code:

```
    $("#btnSave").click(function(){

    var empName = $("#empName").val().trim();  // VALIDATE THIS
    var skillArr = [];
    var empObj = {};

    if(empName != '')
        return false;

        $(".trSkillCls").each(function( index ) {
          // VALIDATE FOR skill and level
            if($(this).find('input[name=skill]').val().trim() == '' || $(this).find('select[name=ddlSkillLevel] option:selected').text().trim() == '')
                return false;

                skillObj = {
                    "skill" : $(this).find('input[name=skill]').val(),
                    "level" : $(this).find('select[name=ddlSkillLevel] option:selected').text()
                };                  
                skillArr.push(skillObj);                
        }); 

        empObj = {
            "empName" : $("#empName").val(),
            "skillDetails"  : skillArr
        };  

        $.post( "indexBase.php",
            $('#str').val(JSON.stringify(empObj)),                               
            function(info){                             
                var result = JSON.parse(info);                                                              


                $( "#divEmpDetails" ).empty();

                $("#divEmpDetails").append($("#tmplEmpDetails").render({data:result})); 

                // verify this callback for failures
            }); 

        $("#mainForm").submit( function() {                         
            return false;   
        }); 

        $('.trSkillCls').not(':first').remove();
        $( "#reset" ).trigger( "click" );                   
});
```

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag when your code has nothing to do with this plugin.

Comment: @Sparky Sorry about that..

Comment: This seems like a better fit for the code review site.

Comment: @Pointy it shouldn't matter for people who are new to the programming world and want to learn something from the experts..

Comment: @Surily well perhaps, but I didn't make up the site policies :) If your code is working, and you have no specific questions about some part of the code or some language construct, then Stackoverflow is really not the place for the question.